# error: undefined reference to typeinfo while implementing interface pattern in C++

Tags: c++, qt, design-patterns, namespaces

I'm trying to write an interface based file loader which would be implemented in many ways for different filetypes. I tried every combination that came to my mind or found on stack/the internet but I keep getting the error. What am I doing wrong?

core/loader.h:

```
#ifndef CORE_LOADER_H
#define CORE_LOADER_H

class LoaderInterface
{
    public:
        virtual bool reloadFile();
};

#endif // CORE_LOADER_H
```

core/lodaer/own.h:

```
#ifndef CORE_LOADER_OWN_H
#define CORE_LOADER_OWN_H

#include "src/core/loader.h"

class Own : public LoaderInterface
{
    public:
        bool reloadFile();
};

#endif // CORE_LOADER_OWN_H
```

core/loader/own.cpp:

```
#include "src/core/loader/own.h"

bool Own::reloadFile(){
    return true;
}
```

Linker says:

```
(..)/qt/build-Foo-Desktop_Qt_5_7_0_GCC_64bit-Debug/own.o:-1: error: undefined reference to `typeinfo for LoaderInterface'
```

Comment: It has nothing to do with namespaces. Or Qt. Remove both, and you'll still get the same error.

Comment: @juanchopanza Feel free to suggest a more fitting title then.

Comment: How about "error: invalid use of incomplete type"? That would make it easy to google.

Comment: You're right, thank you

Comment: @BoPersson Why? The problem is the error in the subject and the code above is sufficient to reproduce that error

Comment: @BoPersson Follow one person's tips then get minuses from another person

Comment: @BoPersson but you're right. Still the solution fixes the problem so I've just modified the question once again to match the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you should use *pure virtual function* in the interface class:

```
class LoaderInterface
{
    public:
        virtual bool reloadFile() = 0;
};
```

Comment: To someone who downvoted this answer, please explain why did you do that. It works and looks to me like a solution to my problem. It would be nice if it was also explained though.

Comment: @Luke if you did not include the `= 0` and didn't include a definition for `LoaderInterface::reloadFile` either, the error message wouldn't have been the one in your question.

Comment: Well, it doesn't really tell me why is that happening but I will look for the full explanation in the internet. Thank you all for your help